# Start a line at X column

Tags: spacing, indentation

How can I write a line of text at a given column? I'm using a monospace font
and I have interest in how can I can specify a column number to start from there.
For example:

```
Line started at column zero
    Line started at column five 
        Line started at column nine
```

I only found how to specify an horizontal space in LaTeX units but not in columns. This question comes to my mind playing with a code chunk that I have in a `listing` environment from where I found that I could insert normal text at an exact column position

```
\begin{listing}
    |@Efectively this line start at five position@|
\end{listing}
```

The `|@` and`@|` are my escape characters. Then I ask myself can I do the same without `listing`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `tabbing` environment for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{1em}\=\hspace{1em}\=\hspace{1em}\=\hspace{1em}
\kill
This is at the right margin\\
\>This is at the first tab stop\\
\>\>This is at the second tab stop\\
\>\>\>This is at the third tab stop\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is 1em exactly two `tt`-font characters wide? It looks like it from your image.

Answer (score 1):

A rudimentary version of a command allowing you to specify the indentation as a value depending on the width of a character in mono-spaced font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\texttt{n}}
\newcommand\StCol[2][0]{{\ttfamily\noindent\hspace*{#1\mylen}{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\StCol{Line started at column zero}\\
\StCol[4]{Line started at column five}\\
\StCol[8]{Line started at column nine}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\settowidth` should be in the `\StCol` macro so that different font sizes are taken into account. Alan Munn's answer makes me think that .5em is one `tt`-font character wide. If this is the case `#1\mylen` count be replaced by `#1\dimexpr .5em\relax`.